# Find duplicate in Array with single loop

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

The question is there is and unsorted array and the maximum value should be smaller than the length. I have to find the duplicate record in the array. The condition is to use a loop only once. This is what i have achieved so far. I wanted to know if there was any other approach through which i can achieve this.

```
int[] Arr = { 9, 5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4 };
int[] Arr2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (Arr2[Arr[i]] == 0)
    {
        Arr2[Arr[i]] = Arr[i];
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("duclicate found");
    }       
}
```

Comment: Use a set instead of second array. Before adding to the set, check if the set contains the element - if it does, you have a duplicate. Or you can just check the return value from `Add` - if it's `false`, the element is already present.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: how is it different from the current the approach?

Comment: Never used C# before, but Set ≠ Array, in most programming languages a set means a HashSet, something that enforces a unique constraint on each of its elements.

Comment: its the same in c#. Set ≠ Array. But im concerned about the approach. We are taking a temporary space and comparing them. If it is to be done then we can use lists as well

Comment: Are you sure the input array doesn't contain `0`? Because that would break your solution. Consider `bool[] Arr2`.

Comment: .. do you mean unsorted array of positive integers?

Comment: @tia yes unsorted array of positive integers.

Comment: Then your precondition ensures there must be duplication. Consider array of length 2, it could only be { 1, 1 }.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use any `Set` implementation, say `HashSet<T>`,  e.g.

```
HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
int[] Arr = { 9, 5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4 };

foreach (item in Arr) 
  if (hs.Contains(item)) {
    Console.WriteLine("duplicate found");
    // break; // <- uncomment this if you want one message only
  }
  else 
    hs.Add(item);
```

**Edit:** since `hs.Add` returns `bool` a shorter and more efficient code can be put:

```
HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
int[] Arr = { 9, 5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4 };

foreach (item in Arr) 
  if (!hs.Add(item)) {
    Console.WriteLine("duplicate found");
    // break; // <- uncomment this if you want one message only
  }
```

Comment: this is kind of the same approach? dont you think .

Comment: Yes your approach uses hash. But I would suggest keeping a bit array instead of int array to reduce memory cost.

Comment: @Muneeb Zulfiqar: It works with arbitrary integers, say "int[] Arr = { 5559, -2225, -56, 23, -56 };"

Comment: @Mohit Jain: No; the solution works with arbitrary integers, say "int[] Arr = { 5559, -2225, -56, 23, -56 };", that's why I'd rather not use bit array

Comment: @Dmitry Yes you are right. I was not talking about implementation but about the idea of hashing. Idea is essentially same. I would prefer your way of int sets so that my solution can run on complete range of ints. A set implemented using hash or BST. For such small memory when you are not using standard feature and implementing things by your own (possibly to learn, or array bounds are known), I suggested to prefer bitset.

Comment: @Dmitry : Dosen't the Contains() make it quadratic?

Comment: @Abhi: No; when hash is properly implemented, it's O(1); that's why the algorithm is linear O(n) (loop on array)

Comment: You mean a hash guaranteed with no collisions? How can that be possible? Also this problem can be solved without using any c# structure, Even if .NET then a Dictionary could have been also used to achieve the same affect. In computer science i do not think a Contains() can be called O(1). A Hash is just used for uniform distribution.

Comment: @Abhi: No, hash can't guarantee absence of collisions, but when hash implementted properly, there'll be few collisions and that's why in average Contains will be O(1). However, an adversary, who knows the implemenation, could (in some cases) compute such numbers that make many collistions enough to turn Count into linear. Dictionary is based on hash, so HasSet<T> and Dictionary<K, V> are interchangable in the solution.

Comment: Exactly, so in the very worst case your implementation is Quadratic. As an average case is very hard to get right. Also this question does not need any complex data structures :-) Even the .NET dictionaries and Hash Sets just hash to achieve uniform distribution. That's why you always need to override a `Equals()` with `GetHashCode()`

Answer (score 3):

Since you have this condition :

`The question is there is and unsorted array and the maximum value should be smaller than the length.`

Also assuming only `positive` numbers, which in your example applies

This can be done using `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space without using any LINQ, Dictionary, Hashing etc.

```
int[] arr = { 9, 5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4 };
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
     if (arr[Math.Abs(arr[i])] >= 0)
         arr[Math.Abs(arr[i])] = -arr[Math.Abs(arr[i])];
     else
         Console.WriteLine("Duplicate found " + Math.Abs(arr[i]).ToString() + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the [**Element Distinctness Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).

This problem cannot be solved strictly linearly without additional space.

The two common approaches to solve the problem are:

1. Using a HashSet - populate it while iterating and abort if you find a match - O(n) time on average and O(n) space
2. Sort and iterate, after the array is sorted, duplicates will be adjacent to each other and easy to detect. This is `O(nlogn)` time and very little extra space.

Comment: the condition is to only loop once. how can you sort and compare in a single loop?

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar `foreach (var a in Arr.OrderBy(s => s))`

Comment: OrderBy this loops more than once sir

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar This answer aims to show you that not everything that we want can be done. This problem cannot be solved in a single loop without additional space, this should give you a hint you're on the right track.

Comment: @amit i had the same vision, i just needed some expert opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to obtain all duplicates, using LINQ, is this:

```
var duplicates = Arr.GroupBy(s => s).SelectMany(d => d.Skip(1));
```

This will return an `IEnumerable` of all duplicate elements in `Arr`, and you can use the following check to contain if there were any duplicates:

```
if (duplicates.Any())
{
    // We have a duplicate!
}
```

Comment: Linq cannot pe used. because it will violate the condition of using single loop.

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar You're right, `GroupBy` actually loops three times just to sort. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work if only array `a[]` contains numbers in range `[0,n-1]` `{as in your question}` and n is not very large to avoid integer range overflow .

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[a[i]%n]>=n)
         **duplicate is a[i]** !
    else   
    a[a[i]%n]+=n;

}
```

Time complexity : O(N)
**Space complexity : O(1)** !

Answer (score 0):

try this code  using LINQ

```
    int[] listOfItems = new[] { 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 4, 3 };
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
foreach (var d in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine("The duplicate is "+d);
```