# Write a program in C# and ask the user to enter 5 unique numbers

Tags: c#, console-application, unique, user-input

> Write a program and ask the user to enter 5 numbers. If a number has
> been previously entered, display an error message and ask the user to
> retry. Once the user successfully enters 5 unique numbers, sort them
> and display the result on the console.

Can anybody please help me on this one? I'm really confused on how to solve this. Here's my code:

```
var number = new int[5];
Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 unique numbers");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var numberValue = number[i];

    var currentNumber = Array.IndexOf(number, numberValue);
    if (number[i] == number[0])
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!(currentNumber == number[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hold on, you already entered that number. Try again.");
        }
    }

    /* foreach (var n in number) { ... } */
    continue;
}

Array.Sort(number);
Console.WriteLine();

foreach (var n in number)
    Console.WriteLine(n);

Console.WriteLine();
```

I can't find the solution on the checking if there is already the same number input. Help me please. And please explain why it is the answer.

PS: Can you please only use simple code and do not use keywords like HashSet? I know that will solve the problem but I don't know it yet. I'm just trying to learn C# step by step so I'm sorry for that.. Thank you!

Comment: do not use a for (5) loop but a while (list_of_input.Count<5) loop. Also: Avoid arrays for List<T> and make use of its Contains method.

Comment: As an aside: try to avoid nested if's and too many `continue` statements

Comment: Okay thank you for your tip. But how will that help me figure out the answer to my question?

Comment: You should check with `if (currentNumber == -1)` if the element is NOT in an array. The indexOf method will return -1 is not present in the array and valid index of 0 - n if valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate in Array with single loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930266/find-duplicate-in-array-with-single-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var number = new int[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 unique numbers");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var newValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                var currentNumber = Array.IndexOf(number, newValue);
                if (currentNumber == -1)
                {
                    number[i] = newValue; // Accept New value
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Hold on, you already entered that number. Try again.");
            }
        }

        Array.Sort(number);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var n in number)
            Console.WriteLine(n);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

`Array.IndexOf()` returns index of `numberValue` in array, or -1 if it does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

Let's *extract a method* and use a `HashSet<int>` to ensure numbers being *unique*:

```
   using System.Linq; // We are going to use .ToArray()

   ...

   private static int[] ReadUniqueNumbers(int count) {
     HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();

     Console.WriteLine($"Enter {count} unique numbers"); 

     while (numbers.Count < count) {
       int number = 0;

       if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))  
         Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Not a valid integer value. Try again.");
       else if (!numbers.Add(number))
         Console.WriteLine("Hold on, you already entered that number. Try again."); 
     }

     // Or if you want ordered array
     // return numbers.OrderBy(item => item).ToArray(); 
     return numbers.ToArray(); 
   }

...

   int[] number = ReadUniqueNumbers(5);
```

**Edit:** Let's use *good old loops*, without `HashSet` and *Linq*:

```
   private static int[] ReadUniqueNumbers(int count) {
     int[] result = new int[count];
     int numberCount = 0;

     while (numberCount < count) {
       int number = 0;

       // When working with user input we should be ready for any string:
       // user may well input "bla-bla-bla" (not an integer at all)
       if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))  
         Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Not a valid integer value. Try again.");
       else {
         bool found = false;

         // Do we have duplicates? 
         // Linq (for reference only)
         // found = result.Take(numberCount).Any(item => item == number);
         for (int i = 0; i < numberCount; ++i)
           if (result[i] == number) {
             found = true; 

             break;
           }

         if (found) // Duplicate found
           Console.WriteLine("Hold on, you already entered that number. Try again."); 
         else {
           result[numberCount] = number;
           numberCount += 1; 
         }
       }  
     }

     return result;       
   }
```

Comment: At first I thought about answering something along the lines of this but the OP is clearly a beginner and he works with arrays not collections, besides an ideal code is not necessarily an ideal answer (It might have zero value for the OP without further explanation)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has got a down vote! May be the OP is a beginner and is currently working with arrays. But he should be keen enough to learn new things. If he is not interested in at least googling what exactly a Hashset is after seeing this answer, then I dont think he deserves a reply.

Comment: @Developer - I'm sorry if I mistakenly clicked the up and down votes. I'm clicking the up votes for everyone's answer because I'm thankful they gave at least part of their time to look on to my question here. And sorry too if I said that I'm looking for answer which have been coded in the simplest form. I'm a beginner yes. I'm learning C# without any guidance from pro. I'm just watching videos from different sources. Maybe I'm not a fast learner like you. I just want to learn this language step by step for me to fully understand what I'm learning. 
Thanks.

Comment: @Developer If the OP was keen to google what exactly Hashset is he wouldn't have asked such a basic question...

Comment: Actually, I googled HashSet earlier when sir Dmitry used it in his original code. However, I don't want to load so much information in my head. I just want to fully grasp what I'm learning on the video sources I'm watching. Sorry if I'm not like other people when it comes to learning. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var numberValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var currentNumberIndex = Array.IndexOf(number, numberValue);
    if (currentNumberIndex >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hold on, you already entered that number. Try again.");
        i--;
    }
    else
    {
        number[i] = numberValue;
    }
}
```

`Array.IndexOf()` returns index of `numberValue` in array, or -1 if it does not exist

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, but note that OP has already saved the number in the array, and you need to avoid matching a 0 for index >= i that will be there by default.

Comment: I don´t understand

Comment: By default the number[] array will be initialized to five zeros. So if I enter '0' then it will be found in the array even if it isn't a duplicate yet.

Comment: However even if I don't enter 0 the my number will always be found in the array. Your first line inside the loop puts the number in the array at index i, so if there is no duplicate then currentNumberIndex will be i because it's found the one you've just added.

Answer (score 1):

```
  List<Int32> Numbers=new List<Int32>();
  Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 unique numbers");

  while (Numbers.Count<5) {
    int result=-1;
    Boolean IsNumber=Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out result);
    if (IsNumber==false) {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number!!!");
      continue;
    }

    if (Numbers.IndexOf(result)>=0) {
      Console.WriteLine("Hold on, you already entered that number. Try again.");
      continue;
    }
    Numbers.Add(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pasted their answers, but here goes my strategy. It uses a nullable array and `Contains` to avoid iterating through the numbers in the array each time the user types a number.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = new int?[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Please enter number {i+1}.");

        do
        {
            int n;
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number. Please try again.");

            var currentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(n);
            var containsNumber = numbers.Contains(currentNumber);

            if (!containsNumber)
            {
                numbers[i] = currentNumber;
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Number was entered previously, please enter a different number.");
        } while (true);


    }

    Console.Clear();
    Array.Sort(numbers);

    foreach (int? n in numbers)
        Console.WriteLine(n);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = new HashSet<int>(); // accepts only unique values

while (input.Count() < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter value");

    int temp; // In newer C# it can be moved to TryParse e.g "out int temp"
    if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp))
    {
        if (input.Contains(temp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this number is already in collection");
        }
        else
        {
            input.Add(temp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("incorrect value");
    }
}
// order by(lambda_expression) allows you to specify by "what things" 
// you'd want to order that collection. In this case you're just sorting 
// by numbers, but if it was complex objects collection then you'd be
// able to sort by e.g student => student.Money; which would mean that 
// you're sorting students by their Money count.
foreach (var number in input.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: Note this part of the requirement _"If a number has been previously entered, display an error message and ask the user to re-try"_

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var numbers = new List<int>();
    while(numbers.Count() < 5)
    {
      var line = Console.ReadLine();
      int number;
      if (int.TryParse(line, out number)) {
        if (numbers.Contains(number))
          Console.WriteLine("You already entered " + line);
        else
          numbers.Add(number);
      } else
        Console.WriteLine(line + " is not a number");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers.OrderBy(i => i)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace exercise2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

     {
                //exercise 2 : question 3
                Console.WriteLine("Please write 5 numbers");
                var array = new int[5];
                const int loop_leng = 5;

                for(var i = 0; i < loop_leng; i++)
                {
                    var input = Console.ReadLine();
                    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Re-try");
                        break;
                    }
                    int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                    foreach (var x in array)
                    {
                        if (numbers == x)
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine("don't repeat! re-try..");
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                    array[i] = numbers;

                    var a = Array.IndexOf(array, numbers);
                    var b = Array.LastIndexOf(array, numbers);
                    if(a != b)
                    { 
                    if(array[a] == array[i])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                }
                { 
                Console.WriteLine();
                Array.Sort(array);
                foreach (var n in array)
                    Console.WriteLine(n);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ControlFlow
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numbers = new int[5];
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Numbers:");
                var checkThisNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (numbers.Contains(checkThisNumber))
                {
                    i -= 1;
                    continue;
                }

                numbers[i] = checkThisNumber;

            }
            Array.Sort(numbers);
            foreach (var num in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem. You can divide this into four steps:

1. Read input from the console.
2. Check if it is a valid integer.
3. Check if it has been entered before.
4. Repeat until the required number of unique integers are obtained.

You can write functions for each of these subtasks:

```
public static int?[] ReadUniqueIntegers(int count)
{
        int?[] uniqueNumbers = new int?[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            int number = ReadIntegerFromConsole();

            // If the number entered above already exists, the IsIntegerAlreadyExisting will return true and the while loop runs until a unique value is entered
            while (IsIntegerAlreadyExisting(number, uniqueNumbers)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Integer already entered. Enter a unique integer:");
                number = ReadIntegerFromConsole();
            }
            uniqueNumbers[i] = number;
        }
        return uniqueNumbers;
    }
```

Now you need the functions for the subtasks:

```
public static int ReadIntegerFromConsole()
{
    // Read line as string
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer");
    String input = Console.ReadLine();
     int inputAsInteger;


    // Keep reading console input until it is a valid integer
    while (!int.TryParse(input, out inputAsInteger) {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter an integer");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    return inputAsInteger;
}
```

```
public static bool IsIntegerAlreadyExisting(int newInteger, int[] numbers)
{
    foreach (var integer in numbers)
    {
         if (integer == newInteger)
         {
            // an existing integer is the same as the newly entered integer
             return true;
         }
    }
    // no integer equals the new integer
    return false;
}
```

Now you can use your `ReadUniqueNumbers()` like this:

```
int[] fiveUniqueNumbers = ReadUniqueNumbers(5);
```

The default value of an `int` in an array is `0`. So, if you create a new array of size 5, it will by default contain five 0s. And if you enter `0`, you will get it already exists even for the first time. To prevent this, use `int?[]` instead of `int[]`. An `int?[]` (nullable int) array will have a default value of `null` instead of `0`.

### Full Code

```
public class Program 
{
    public static int?[] ReadUniqueIntegers(int count)
    {
        int?[] uniqueNumbers = new int?[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            int number = ReadIntegerFromConsole();

            // If the number entered above already exists, the IsIntegerAlreadyExisting will return true and the while loop runs until a unique value is entered
            while (IsIntegerAlreadyExisting(number, uniqueNumbers)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Integer already entered. Enter a unique integer:");
                number = ReadIntegerFromConsole();
            }
            uniqueNumbers[i] = number;
        }
        return uniqueNumbers;
    }
    
    public static int ReadIntegerFromConsole()
    {
        // Read line as string
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer");
        String input = Console.ReadLine();

        int inputAsInteger;
        // Keep reading console input until it is a valid integer
        while (!int.TryParse(input, out inputAsInteger )) {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter an integer");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return inputAsInteger;
    }

    public static bool IsIntegerAlreadyExisting(int newInteger, int?[] numbers)
    {
        foreach (var integer in numbers)
        {
            if (integer == newInteger)
            {
                // an existing integer is the same as the newly entered integer
                return true;
            }
        }
        // no integer equals the new integer
        return false;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int?[] numbers = ReadUniqueIntegers(5);

        Console.WriteLine("Entered numbers are: ");
        foreach (var number in numbers) 
        {
            Console.Write(number + " ");
        }       
    }
}
```